# Let A be any set. Is the set of all things not in A well-defined? Is it even a set? Do we absolutely need a "universal" set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Let A be any set. Is this set $B=\{x\mid x\notin A\}$ well-defined? Is it even a set?
I kind of already know that the answers to those two questions are two "no"s, but I still feel a bit uncomfortable about it. I'm not really sure exactly why it's not well-defined and I don't know what the consequences of accepting such sets would be. My actual question is that: Exactly why is it considered ill-defined? What would the consequences of accepting sets like that be? Would we arrive at a contradiction?

A question related to this one that I'd also like to ask is if it's absolutely necessary to define a "universal" set. Couldn't we simply define it as the set containing everything except itself?. What are the consequences of trying to do this? Again, would we arrive at a contradiction?

EDIT: To be clearer, when I say "things not in A" I'm referring to absolutely EVERYTHING that exists in the physical and mental worlds, not just in the universe of Mathematics. Similarly, when I ask if we could define the universal set as the set containing everything except itself, I'm referring to EVERYTHING, not just all mathematical objects.

Comment: Most of the time you would not use the notation $B= \lbrace x : x \notin A \rbrace$ since you didn't specify the range of the variable $x$ to the left of $:$. Sometimes it is done in a context where it is clear what set the $x$'s are supposed to be members of.

Comment: To be clearer, the notation $B= \lbrace x : x \notin A \rbrace$ is meaningless as it stands right now. If you specified that the $x$ are members of $A$ then the expression does make sense and is the empty set.

Comment: @Bartuc: That is not true at all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila which part?

Comment: All of it, really. Of course it makes sense to talk about all the things which are not in $A$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila wouldn't you always, atleast implicitly, specify a universal set, acting as a universe of discourse in some sense?

Comment: @Bartuc: The universe of mathematics is not enough for you?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have never actually gotten used to the idea of quantifying over the entire universe of mathematics. But then again, I am not a set theorist. To my mind, it would be somewhat meaningless to speak of the entire universe of mathematics as if it is a thing. Is the fundamental group of the torus for example a member of $B$? I wouldn't know and I surely don't think anyone would find it meaningful to ask that question.

Comment: @Bartuc: If $A$ happens to be $\{G\}$ where $G$ is the fundamental group of the torus, then the answer is of course negative. If $A$ happens to be empty, then the answer is positive.

Comment: @AsafKaragila okay sure, but then you have already added something more to the context than what the OP has provided, no?

Comment: @Bartuc: I don't see how, though.

Comment: Uhh, your edit makes no sense and makes this question to be not about mathematics anymore. I would have suggested to the Philosophy.SE website, but I don't think it will be accepted very well there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think it boils down to what you said in your answer. I think of sets more like that of ETCS style set theory or naive set theory, where there is always a context specified perhaps implicitly.

Comment: @Bartuc: I don't see how ETCS would change this. In naive set theory, sure. Because naive set theory is naive. But we are not naive anymore, when it comes to set theoretic questions. Only some people *choose* to be naive... :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see the OP meant the question in a more philosophical way, so no point in going further into the question mathematically. In ETCS, wouldn't you have to regiment the statement occurring as the defining condition, since $a \notin A$ means something different than in ZFC say?

Comment: @user115859: You can't even define a set of all the mathematical objects (yes, you get a logical absurd), of course you can't define a set of "everything".

Comment: @VincenzoOliva What logical absurd? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @user115859: Russell's paradox, amongst other paradoxes of naive set theory, showed that not every property defines a set. And again, if you talk about non-mathematical objects, then they cannot be elements of a set, because sets are by definition "mathematical objects which are themselves collections of mathematical objects".

Comment: @user11859: Suppose $S$ is the set of all sets. By the axiom of specification there exists $A=\{x\in S | x\not\in x\}$. Now, is $A$ an element of itself? Well, we can see that $A\in A \iff A\not\in A$, not very nice.

Comment: In particular, with that construction, you can always construct a set $A$ which is not an element of a given set $S$. You may want to look up [Grothendieck universes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) if you're not satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-defined collection, assuming you are talking about mathematical objects (otherwise this is not a mathematical question anymore, and has no place here). Yes. And in *most* cases, it is not a set.

Some context is often need to interpret things. If I were reading a paper about some combinatorial properties of some natural numbers, of course that I would interpret something like $\{n\mid\text{ such and such holds for }n\}$ as a set of natural numbers.

In most other cases, though, I would probably treat an unbounded quantification as ranging over all the mathematical universe. Which for me, and for other people perhaps as well, this would mean the set theoretic universe.

Now comes the question. What is your set theory of choice? In the case of $\sf ZFC$, its close relatives and its descendants, there is no "set of everything". So $\{x\mid x\notin A\}$ is a proper class. It is still a valid thing to talk about and use in your work.

In other cases, such as $\sf NF$, there is in fact a universal set, so $\{x\mid x\notin A\}$ is indeed a set.

In other other cases, such as positive set theory, only positive formulas can define sets, so certainly $x\notin A$ does not define a set.

---

To sum up. Yes, this is a well-defined collection, and in some contexts it would also make a set. In other contexts it would not, and some people would consider it somewhat meaningless without sufficient context anyway. So your mileage may vary depending on what you're doing, where you're doing it, and with whom you're trying to talk about it.

Comment: Sorry, I confused NF with NBG.

Answer (score 0):

In elementary set theory, a set can be defined as $B=\{x\mid P(x)\}$ where $P(x)$ is a predicate in the free variable $x$ such as ''$x$ is prime'' or ''$x$ is not prime''. But the context is important and so it would be better to define ''$x$ is a natural number which is prime'' or ''$x$ is a natural number which is not prime''.